# Firestore security rules, restricting child/field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

What is the equivalent way of Firebase RTDB's `newData.hasChildren(['name', 'age', 'gender'])` in Firestore? How to restrict the child/field?

**Update:**
I have updated my question with Firestore rules and explained my issue in detail.

```html
match /{country} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow create: if isAdministrator()
               && incomingData().countryCode is string
               && incomingData().dialCode is string;
  allow update: if (isAdministrator() || isAdminEditor())
               && incomingData().countryCode is string
               && incomingData().dialCode is string;
  allow delete: if isAdministrator();
}
```

`create`, `read` and `delete` is working as expected. But if I try to update using `Hashmap` with any unmentioned child, it will update without throwing any exception unlike Firebase Database rules, where we mention all the possible childs in `newData.hasChildren([])`.

Comment: Your update rule doesn't seem to be checking the written data at all.  What exactly is the rule that's not working the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my `update` rule. Now if I try to update using a not mentioned child, say 'countryAliasName' or something, it will update without throwing any exception. How could this be avoided.?

Comment: What is `incomingData()`?

Comment: @DougStevenson My bad, I'm sorry. `icomingData()` is `request.resource.data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing right now is just checking if two provided field values are strings.  You're not requiring that only those to fields exist in the update data.  What you can do is use the [`keys()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#keys) method of the data map to verify that only certain fields exist in the update.  For example, this may work:

```
request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['countryCode', 'dialCode'])
```

There are a number of other methods available on [List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) objects to help you determine its contents.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank u :)